# data type in html

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, jquery-plugins

Can you tell me what `data-carouselType` means?

```
<div class="Carousel" data-carselType="magazine">
```

They have used (in jQuery code):

```
if ($this.attr("data-carselType") === "magazine") {
                $(prevBtn).addClass("opaque");
                $(nextBtn).addClass("opaque");
                this.appendChild(prevBtn);
                this.appendChild(nextBtn);
                pagerWidth = $(prevBtn).width();
                childLength = $kids.children().length;
                $kids.css("left", pagerWidth + "px").children("div").addClass("grouping");
                childWidth = $kids.children("div").width();
                leftMagTitle = document.createElement("div");
                rightMagTitle = document.createElement("div");
                prevBtn.appendChild(leftMagTitle);
                nextBtn.appendChild(rightMagTitle);
                $kids.width(childLength * childWidth);
                $kids.children(":first-child").addClass("active");
                $kids.css("left", (pagerWidth - $this.find(".caroContainer").children("div").width()) + "px");

                forPrependingOne = $kids.children(":eq(" + (childLength - 1) + ")").clone();
                $kids.children(":eq(" + (childLength - 1) + ")").remove();
                $kids.prepend(forPrependingOne);

                $kids.click(function (e) {
                    link = $(e.target).parents(this).children("a").attr("href");
                    if ($(e.target).parents(this) && e.target.tagName !== "IMG" && e.target.tagName !== "INPUT" && e.target.tagName !== "A" && link !== undefined) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        document.location = link;
                    }
                });

                lazyLoad();
```

Comment: Its an [html5 data attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a custom attribute. Inventor wanted someway to annotate certain HTML elements with this attribute so that they could be referenced (e.g. by the code you provided)